# SDSS ImgCutout webservice returns black image for dr12

Tags: observational-astronomy, sky-survey

The SDSS (Sloan Digital Sky Survey) ImgCutout webservice should return jpeg images for a given field that is defined by the parameters. The service can be tested here: http://skyservice.pha.jhu.edu/DR12/ImgCutout/ImgCutout.asmx?op=GetJpeg

A simple (and working) get query is given here:
http://skyservice.pha.jhu.edu/DR12/ImgCutout/getjpeg.aspx?ra=132.749&dec=11.656&scale=0.79224%20%20%20&width=400&height=400&opt=

If you enter the same information (the parameters) in the form of the first link and click on invoke you will get a black image only. You can test the base64 encoded result here: http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/

**Description of how to reproduce my findings:**

1. Go to http://skyservice.pha.jhu.edu/DR12/ImgCutout/ImgCutout.asmx?op=GetJpeg
2. Fill parameter 'ra_' with '132.749'
3. Fill parameter 'dec_' with '11.656'
4. Fill parameter 'scale_' with '0.79224'
5. Fill parameter 'width_' with '400'
6. Fill parameter 'height_' with '400'
7. Press 'Invoke' button
8. Convert the content in the `<base64Binary>` tag from base64 to a jpeg

Following this steps I always get a black image.

**Now the question:**

Do I require an additional parameter (non empty string) for either `imgtype_` or `imageField_` in order to not get the correct image? What are this parameters good for anyway?

(Is there a better place this question? It would be nice if there was a tag for SDSS)

Comment: Well the image is not black when I try it ....

Comment: I tried again and still get a black image. Did you follow the same steps as I now described in more detail (see my recent edit).